# Will VS2012 automatically install .NET 4.5 ? Should I use VS2012 or VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5

Firstly, I honestly would like to mention that, I don't know anything in Windows 8. (The OS features, Development for Windows app store or even Windows 8 Phone).

Secondly, I do have VS2010 and .NET 4.0 installed and have been working with this for past 2 years nearly.

Now, my question is,

1. Should I install the VS2012 ? (As why I raised this question is because, I don't know its features, also some say there is some complexity of many new things)
2. I have downloaded VS2012. However, if I install, will it automatically install .NET 4.5 ? I am also worried that, .NET 4.5 has some bugs and since I found that .NET 4.5 is a replacement of 4.0 libraries including CLR, will I have issues in further development ?
3. If I install VS2012, what will happen to my already existing VS 2010 and 4.0 ? Will I not be able to use VS2010 for developing apps for .NET 4.0 (Or secondly 3.5 apps) as the libraries would be replaced as 4.5 ?
4. What's the version of C# associated with .NET4.5/VS2012. Is it C#4.0 ? or 4.5 or 5.0 ?

I appreciate if someone can help me with this, letting me understand my above questions individually, as I am a novice to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Maybe.
   It has a cleaner UI, a much better Javascript experience, and language-level async support
2. Yes; VS 2012 is built on .Net 4.5
3. All .Net 4.0 apps will use the .Net 4.5 BCL.
   There aren't very many compatibility issues
4. C# 5.0.
   C#, unlike .Net, has never had non-integer version numbers.

Comment: thank you so much for guiding me, will goahead and install and explore the new UI and also Windows 8 app/mobile development :) Cheers